# Adding Custom Header Tags to an Enyo Project

Tags: javascript, enyo

I'd like to add some custom meta tags to my enyo project, such that they will be added to the `index.html` file generated when I run `enyo pack`.

In older versions of enyo there was simply an index.html file that could be modified, but I have no idea how to do this now.

The `--template-index` option of `enyo pack` seems a likely bet, but I can't find documentation for it anywhere to indicate what a template index should look like. However, even if I could, it seems like something of an overkill option when it comes to just adding a few custom tags.

What is the simplest method for adding meta tags to the output for an enyo 2.7 project?

Answer (score 0):

You'll either need to use the template option or post-process your `index.html` file.  You can see a little bit more about how to create a template file in this forum post:

http://forums.enyojs.com/discussion/comment/10409#Comment_10409